# One Angular controller that will be used in multiple apps

Tags: angularjs

So when you define a controller in angular, you do so this way.

```
angular.module('AppName').controller('ControllerName', function ($scope, $location, dataService, commonMethods) {
});
```

How would you take this and make the same controller be used in two different apps?

```
angular.module('AppName1').controller('ControllerName', function ($scope, $location, dataService, commonMethods) {
});

angular.module('AppName2').controller('ControllerName', function ($scope, $location, dataService, commonMethods) {
});
```

Comment: Separate the creation of the controller from the `controller` call. IOW, move `function ($scope, $location, dataService, commonMethods) {
}` outside of `controller`, name it, then use that name in the controller call: `.controller('ControllerName', nameOfController);`.

Comment: What if you create a common module with the controller definition in it and use that module instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate module with all of the items you share between various apps (controllers, services, etc.) and then just inject that module into any apps that require those items.

So in something like shared.js you have:

```
angular.module("shared")
.controller(...)
.service(...)
.constant(...)
```

Then make sure you load the shared.js file before your app's module file and then inject it with:

angular.module("app","shared")

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what modules are for, to make the application modular.

```
angular.module('some', []).controller('SomeController', ...);
...
angular.module('app1', ['some']);
...
angular.module('app2', ['some']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your services, factories, directives, etc.  into SEPARATE js files, and each begin with .    Then just include the .js file.

```
// Constants.js
.constant('Constants', {
    Initialize_IntervalMilliseconds: {
        defltTimeout: 50,
        longTimeout: 250
    }
});

// factoryGlobal.js
myTable.factory('factGlobal', function () {
    return {
        BaseURL: "http://localhost:6/api/", 
        etc = ""
    };
});
```

You can use them for multiple modules.  Quite nice

Comment: I don't think you can wrap any of those items in an IIFE if you go that route.